# In Python, how to create a new binary variable in 1 column coming from multiple categories in another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categorical-data, dummy-variable

An example to illustrate the point. In 1 column, there are the following 5 categories for "food_spice_levels".

high_heat, medium_heat, mild_heat, no_heat, bland

The goal is to create a new binary variable called "Spiciness" to show whether the food is spicy or not spicy. Bland, no_heat, mild_heat, and medium_heat = 0, and High_heat = 1 is the goal and again, to be in 1 new column.

Current code and issues:

df['Spiciness'] = df['food_spice_levels'].map({'Bland''no_heat''mild_heat''medium_heat': 0, 'high_heat': 1})

Commas between each category in the code for the "0" category gave a syntax error. Without the commas, this warning came:

"SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead"

It did create a new column with high_heat being coded as "1" correctly, but all the desired "0" values got coded to "NaN" and I don't want to destroy the dataset if the warning is telling me something that can't be ignored. Can anyone help so that I get 0's and 1's in the new column while potentially avoiding this error message. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'food': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D', 4: 'E', 5: 'F'}, 'food_spice_levels': {0: 'bland', 1: 'high_heat', 2: 'mild_heat', 3: 'medium_heat', 4: 'high_heat', 5: 'bland'}})
print(df)
#   food food_spice_levels
# 0    A             bland
# 1    B         high_heat
# 2    C         mild_heat
# 3    D       medium_heat
# 4    E         high_heat
# 5    F             bland

df['binary'] = (df['food_spice_levels']=='high_heat').astype(int)
print(df)
#   food food_spice_levels  binary
# 0    A             bland       0
# 1    B         high_heat       1
# 2    C         mild_heat       0
# 3    D       medium_heat       0
# 4    E         high_heat       1
# 5    F             bland       0
```

This utilizes the fact that booleans are represented as `1` (`True`) or `0` (`False`). The part `df['food_spice_levels']=='high_heat'` creates a boolean series, which then is parsed as `int`.